# Android emulator not connecting to internet in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to create a webview and load simple page in it in android xamarin. My manifest has the  setting still it is not able to connect to internet. When I am trying to connect to internet with the default web browser in the emulator, it says the webpage cannot be loaded. How should I make it connect to internet?

Comment: 1. Put Internet access permission in AndroidManifest.xml         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />         2. Tell me whether internet symbol on your emulator is showing or not??

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I had to set up the proxy settings in the emulator